# My second IF seems to be executing and it shouldn't be

Tags: powershell, active-directory, logic

I am trying to tidy up a large number of AD users, to do this I have created another script to crowd source some of the work.  This script prompts the user for their EmployeeID and puts it and some other AD info into ExterntionAttrib4 like this.

```
a999:adminhearsj:Jason:Hearse
```

This script will become a scheduled task which should.

Check for ExterntionAttrib4 if it exists and EmployeeID is empty then check a CSV file with HR info.

```
Firstname,Lastname,EmployeeID,
jason,HEARSE,A999
fred,blogs,999
```

If the users EMployeeId matches the HR EmployeeID and a name check (to be added later) then write to the AD EmployeeID.

If the users EmployeeID doesn't match an entry from HR then remove ExterntionAttrib4 and they will be prompted again to enter the details next logon.

The problem is that when I run this script after writing AD EmployeeID it then still removes ExterntionAttrib4.

There are a lot of `Write-Host`s as I have been trying to get to the bottom of this, I think it is because while in the `foreach Get-ADUser` I am falling through each entry in the HR.CSV file.

I have tried various different ways to invoke the `if` logic and I know the statements could be shorter but I have stretched them out to help me see what's happening.

```
# Import-module activedirectory

cls

# temp search base
$SearchBase = 'OU=Admin-account,DC=corp,DC=internal'
$searchproperties = ("sAMAccountName","UserPrincipalName","Enabled","sn","givenName","Initials","CN","DistinguishedName","EmployeeID","EmployeeNumber","Title","info","Company","Department","Office","Country","City","co","countryCode","Description","EmailAddress","msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed","st","State","StreetAddress","PostalCode","codePage","extensionAttribute1","extensionAttribute2","extensionAttribute3","extensionAttribute4","extensionAttribute5","extensionAttribute6","extensionAttribute7","extensionAttribute8","extensionAttribute9","extensionAttribute10","extensionAttribute11","extensionAttribute12","extensionAttribute13","extensionAttribute14","extensionAttribute15","Fax","PasswordNeverExpires")#,$hash_lastLogonTimestamp,$hash_pwdLastSet)

$SAM = ""

$logfolder = "C:\Users\adminhearsj\Documents\Scripts\users\Attrib search\logs"
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
$failedUsers = @()
$userEMPwrong = @()
$successUsers = @()
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

# remove or change searchbase 
# AD Search

$ADusers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $searchbase -Filter {(extensionAttribute4 -like '*') -and (Employeeid -notlike '*')} -Properties * |
           select $searchproperties 
foreach ($ADuser in $ADusers) {
    # $ADusers
    $attrib = $ADuser.extensionAttribute4
    $ADgivenName = $ADuser.givenName
    $ADsn = $ADuser.sn
    $ADEmpID = $ADusers.EmployeeID
    $SAM = $ADusers.sAMAccountName

    $delimEMP = ($attrib -split ':')[0]
    $delimSAM = ($attrib -split ':')[1]
    $delimGivenName = ($attrib -split ':')[2]
    $delimSN = ($attrib -split ':')[3]

    Write-Host ATTR4 $attrib
    Write-Host USER Emp $delimEMP ADsam $delimSAM $delimGivenname $delimSN

    # HR file
    $HRUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\adminhearsj\Documents\Scripts\users\Attrib Search\HR.csv"            

    foreach ($HRUser in $HRUsers) {
        $HRUser.FirstName = $HRUser.FirstName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + $HRUser.FirstName.Substring(1).ToLower()
        $HRUser.LastName = $HRUser.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + $HRUser.LastName.Substring(1).ToLower()
        $FullName = $HRUser.FirstName + " " + $HRUser.LastName
        $Displayname = $HRUser.Lastname + ", " + $HRUser.Firstname
        $dnsroot = '@' + (Get-ADDomain).dnsroot  
        $HRUserFirstname = $HRUser.Firstname            
        $HRUserLastname = $HRUser.Lastname  
        $HREmp = $HRuser.EmployeeID  

        #  -pattern "    $delimEMP'$"
        Write-Host USER Emp $delimEMP HR Emp $HREmp  ADsn $ADsn HR LN $HRUserLastname

        try {
            if ($delimEMP -eq $HREmp) {  #-and $ADEmpID -ne '*') #$ADsn -eq $HRUserLastname)
                Write-Host Delim Emp $delimEMP EQ $HREmp 

                if ($ADEmpID -ne "*") {
                    Set-ADUser -Identity $sam -Replace @{employeeID=$HREmp}
                    $successUsers += $Displayname 
                    Write-Host 1ST IF and AD Emp NULL $ADEmpID
                    Break
                }

                Write-Host MATCH Name 1st IF is USR Emp $delimEMP HR Emp $HREmp written $HREmp
            } else {
                if ($delimEMP -ne $HREmp) {  #-and $ADsn -eq $HRUserLastname -and $EmpID -eq '')
                    if ($delimSAM -eq $sam) {
                        Set-ADUser -Identity $sam -Clear "extensionAttribute4"
                        $failedUsers +=  $Displayname 
                        Write-Host Name ELSE is USR Emp $delimEMP HR Emp $HREmp AD sm $ADsn HR sn $HRUserLastname AD emp $ADEmpID
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "[ERROR]Can't create user [$($FullName)] : $_"
            $failedUsers += $FullName
        }
    }
}

if (!(Test-Path $LogFolder)) {
    Write-Verbose "Folder [$($LogFolder)] does not exist, creating"
    New-Item $LogFolder -Force 
}
Write-verbose "Writing logs"
$failedUsers | ForEach-Object { "$($b).) $($_)"; $b++ } | Out-File -FilePath $LogFolder\FailedUsers.log -Force -Verbose
$successUsers | ForEach-Object { "$($a).) $($_)"; $a++ } | Out-File -FilePath $LogFolder\successUsers.log -Force -Verbose
Write-Host Finished
```

Comment: You have two loops going. Loop 1 loops through AD users based on a `Get-ADUser` output. Loop 2 loops through an HR CSV file. Loop 2 cycles through the entire HR file for every AD user found in loop 1. If you want loop 2 to stop after updating the EmployeeID, you will have to put in a `break` statement right after that update. The `break` will break out of the current loop (loop 2) and allow the rest of loop 1 to process. There is going to be a less complicated way to write this though. You are writing a lot to AD rather than reading first and then writing conditionally.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThings thanks for the reply, the break does leave Extattr4 in place for the first true IF but the second item in the CSV then has the Extattr4 removed do you have any thoughts?

Comment: What does `if ($ADEmpID -ne "*")` accomplish? Do you actually have a `*` character in your field because that is what you are testing against?

Comment: I am looking and testing for an empty (null) property EmployeedID as it is now in a string

Comment: I can see what its doing  ... for every AD account that has EAtrib4 set it is rolling through the HR file each time and its removing the EAtrib4 just not sure how to stop it